# PHP SoapClient::__soapCall

Tags: php, soap

I create a new client, and do a soapcall like this:

```
$client = new SoapClient($strServiceUrl, $params);
$result= $client->$strFunct($arrCallParams);
```

then I "Foreach" through the results. However, the result is not in the same order as it is when we test the method of the soapserver in C++ (in which the soapserver is written).
Any thoughts? Is this normal behaviour?

Comment: return should be an object , try var_dump , see what`s difference , besides , how are you passing parameters ? could you log the others side to check if parameters are passed correctly ?

Comment: Var_dump shows the result in an other order. Serverside checked, parameters are passed correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem appeared to be in a bug in the C++ SOAP Service.